# navigation menu not showing up in mobile view

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my first time dabbling with bootstrap. I downloaded it and now trying it to use it on my existing website. So far it's working great except for navigation bar. I have seen examples where in mobile view it collapses into image which when clicked shows as a dropdown menu.

```
<body id="top">     
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="##navbarCollapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Company Name" id="companyImageID" border="0">
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Calendar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Get Involved</a></li>                           
                    </ul>
                </div>
             </div>
        </nav>

   <!-- Here is form and footer -->

    </div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../include/bs/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Anyone could help me how to get that menu in mobile view? Thanks.

Edit1: Currently the way it's working is, if I resize window, navigation links go under the logo and eventually are hidden in mobile view.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code preventing the navbar link from connecting with the menu, which is identified by the id `navbarCollapse`.  You link is pointing to `##navbarCollapse`, but it should be pointing to `#navbarCollapse`.

Just remove the extra `#` and it should work fine.

Comment: rectified typo, it's still the same.

Comment: It works properly in Bootply: [Demo Link](http://www.bootply.com/PwHEtWxrbZ).  Click on the little mobile icon to see example in mobile.

Comment: Strange as it may sound, the bootply demo is working but not in my code. I'm testing this in Chrome v36

Comment: It's possible that the problem is elsewhere then.

Comment: That's the problem. I can't seem to point it out since morning. Rest of the stuff is working as intended.